# Error when installation Bing Code Search for c# on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I install Bing Code Search for Visual Studio 2012, I get the following error:

```
The installation was unable to install the extension to all the selected products.
```

Here is the install log:

```
2/28/2014 1:04:01 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 2/28/2014 1:04:01 AM -
------------------------------------------- 2/28/2014 1:04:01 AM - Initializing Install... 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM - Extension Details... 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -   Identifier      : 57256a12-e1dc-456b-a9b7-c39957cb4b93 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -   Name      : Bing Code Search for C# 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -  Author          : Microsoft 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -  Version         : 1.0 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -    Description     : This package allows you to search for snippets from the cloud and inserts them into your code without leaving Visual Studio. 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -   Locale          : en-US 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -  MoreInfoURL     : http://codesnippet.research.microsoft.com/ 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -     InstalledByMSI  : False 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : 4.5 2/28/2014 1:04:02 AM -  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -     SignedBy        : Microsoft Corporation 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -  Certificate Info : [Subject]   CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Issuer]   CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Serial Number]   33000000B2E6906F8BE7453D5B0001000000B2

[Not Before]   1/25/2013 5:33:41 AM

[Not After]   4/25/2014 5:33:41 AM

[Thumbprint]   E4EEC5DFB7F413E5A15191DA00D017F97E3A6260

2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -  Supported Products :  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -           Version : 12.0 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -   References      :  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -       ------------------------------------------------------- 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.12.0 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF 12.0 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -        Version      : 12.0 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -      MoreInfoURL  :  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -      Nested       : No 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM -  2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Searching for applicable products... 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated) 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - Global Location 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - Found installed product - ssms 2/28/2014 1:04:04 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.    at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to install that extension a week ago on vs 2013 and it crashed VS all the time. I dont think its ready to be used yet..

Comment: @Marcom: [bing dev center](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/02/17/calling-all-coders-bing-code-search-arrives.aspx) would disagree. ;-) [at]OP: I think this is a VS2013 extensions (and not 12). There may be API conflicts... Also, may be worth commenting on the [add-in's page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1166718-a2d9-4a48-a5fd-504ff4ad1b65) and not here, since it's most likely a vendor issue (given the unsuccessful comments I've read).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly this extension looks for the Pro version of VS and not the Express. You cannot install it with Microsoft Visual Studio Express, and that is the version that it is finding as installed on your computer.